# ReactJS onClick does not work for the button, the function inside onClick is not called

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is the button tag and onclick function :

```
<Button
  id="save-btn"
  className="btn-save"
  disabled={true}
  onClick={handleSaveBtnClick}
  >
   Save
</Button>

const handleSaveBtnClick = () => {console.log("testing")}
```

I'm using another button to enable/disable this button, this is the code for that button:

```
  const handleEditClick = (index) => {
// this is for input fields and it works fine:
        document.querySelectorAll(".card-" + index + " .toggle-edit-input").forEach((field) => {
          field.disabled = !field.disabled;
        });
// this piece of code does not work: 
       document.getElementById("save-btn").disabled = false;
        if (document.getElementById("save-btn").disabled = false) {
          document.getElementById("save-btn").onclick = handleSaveBtnClick;
        }
 };
```

if I remove the disabled option then the button works fine but I need it to be disabled unless edit button is clicked.
what could be wrong here ? I have tried most of the methods

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Answer (score 3):

Your enable/disable code isn't how you do this with React. Instead of directly manipulating the DOM, you use a flag in your state for the component that determines whether the button is enabled, and you set / clear that flag. When your component renders, render the `disabled` attribute using the flag, like this (I used `button` rather than `Button`, not knowing which of the several libs you're using that gives you a `Button` component):

```js
const {useState} = React;

function Example() {
    const [saveEnabled, setSaveEnabled] = useState(true);

    const handleSaveBtnClick = () => {
        console.log("testing");
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <button
                    id="save-btn"
                    className="btn-save"
                    disabled={!saveEnabled}
                    onClick={handleSaveBtnClick}
                >
                   Save
                </button>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>
                    <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        checked={saveEnabled}
                        onClick={() => setSaveEnabled(f => !f)}
                    />
                    Save enabled
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Obviously, the "Save enabled" checkbox there is just so you can see what happens when the flag is set/cleared. The key things are:

- The `saveEnabled` state flag
- Using `disabled={!saveEnabled}` in `Button` (`button`)

Comment: @Emile - Thanks, but please don't do that. I don't use two-space indentation for a reason.

Comment: My goal was to avoid horizontal scrolling, what's the reason, other than personal preference?

Comment: @EmileBergeron - Low vision. The two-space thing is an abomination inflicted on us by 20somethings. :-) Really, we should all be using tabs for accessibility (since for some low vision folks, the best thing is one space and a massive font; for other low vision folks, the best thing is 8+ spaces), but since that isn't an option in snippets, I use four spaces. I can't follow 2 space indentation.

Comment: Low vision is definitely a good reason, though assuming it's a generation thing is... ill-placed accusations, to say the least. I, for one, am a 20-something who used to favor tabs but came to acknowledge the benefits of a common standard for a given language/community/team. That being said, I think we could both win by keeping 4 spaces while avoiding horizontal scrolling with just a couple line breaks, would these be acceptable changes?

Comment: @EmileBergeron - I've done that, I should have broken up that `<input />` in the first place. Re "a common standard," it's useful at the team level, not the language level, IMHO. But for what it's worth, I'd be **very** careful about reformatting code like that. A simple targeted edit to avoid horizontal scrolling is fine, but wholescale reformatting code isn't, it falls under the category of editing for style. :-) Thanks for pointing out the scrolling!

Answer (score -1):

You can also use the "old" but good class component approach instead of functional one as suggested before.

In this case you will need something like this:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  state = {enabled: false}


  handleSaveBtnClick = () => {
    console.log("testing");
  };

  handleEnableBtnClick = () => {
    console.log(this.state);
    let newStatus = !this.state.enabled
    this.setState({ enabled: newStatus })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <button
            id="save-btn"
            className="btn-save"
            disabled={!this.state.enabled}
            onClick={this.handleSaveBtnClick}
          >
            Save
                </button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.enabled} onClick={this.handleEnableBtnClick} />
                    Save enabled
                </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: While it's true that a class component could be used here, it's irrelevant to the question.

Comment: I totally disagree with you Emily. He is clearly learning React and he is at his first stages. My answer solves the problem aswell as the one from T.J. Crowder. It is just another implementation of the same code. Providing multiple solutions for the same problem is always better. Furthermore, the functional solution doesn't work on React version < 16.8 due to the hook. So you can not assert that it is irrelevant to the question from my point of view.